# HttpWebResponse body is unreadable

Tags: c#, http, web, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I created a c# application that would integrate with Picarto.tv.

The problem is during the login stage, where the program has to send a WebRequest to the picarto login server with login details and receive the response. I was successful sending the request, but the response came back completely unreadable and of a length not consistent with what the server sends back during the regular login procedure (as was discovered using Chrome and Firefox development tools).

Here is the code of the function in question:

```
public void login(String username, String password)
    {

        HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://picarto.tv/process/login");

        //Set request headers. 
        loginRequest.Method = "POST";
        loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        loginRequest.Referer = "https://picarto.tv/";
        loginRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        loginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36";
        loginRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/html, */*; q=0.01";
        loginRequest.Headers["accept-encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";

        //If you comment the line below, you the resulting report string becomes 25 bytes long but is displayed only as "?"
        //Otherwise, the report value stays empty.
        loginRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate; //???

        loginRequest.Headers["accept-language"] = "gen-US,en;q=0.8";

        //Set request body
        byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username="+ username + "&password="+ password + "&stayLogged=false");
        loginRequest.ContentLength = request.Length;

        Stream requestStream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        //Get response
        HttpWebResponse loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse) loginRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = loginResponse.GetResponseStream();

        Console.WriteLine("Content length: " + loginResponse.ContentLength);  //Always -1.

        //Read response body
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string report = reader.ReadToEnd(); //The report is always either empty or unreadable.

        //Display response body
        Console.WriteLine("length: " + report.Length+ " report: " +report);
        reader.Close();
    }
```

I have used Fiddler and determined that, regardless of the configuration, the response has a 36-40 byte body, but Fiddler itself is unable to decode the message and instead discards it when prompted to decode.

My first thought was that the message is encoded but C# can't decode it because of some internal reason, but my colleague has fed the resultant body to a gzip decoder and determined that the response body is not a valid gzip stream.

I have tried to mimic the login request as close as possible, but apparently something is missing.

I know the code is messy and lacks many important structures (like exception management blocks). I have left those out on purpose for the brevity of the presentation and your convenience.

Edit 1: As suggested (in a post that appears to be deleted at the moment), I tried altering my `loginRequest.AutomaticDecompression` value to `DecompressionMethods.None` and commenting the `accept-encoding` header. The situation hasn't changed, with the exception that the Fiddler now registers only 5 bytes sent back in the body of the response (and still can't decode it).